# Visual Studio 2015 error loading Class Diagram .cd file

Tags: visual-studio-2015, class-diagram

I continually get this error while loading a Class diagram created in VS 2015
"Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

(And the diagram doesn't show up!)

Just a moment before the diagram was opening just fine !!!

I have tried to remove some of the latest added classes but I continue to get same error...

There is a detailed Visual Studio log?

**Note**. During the diagram creation, I have made a copy of diagram at a stage in which I was sure it was opening fine. Now, if I try to open it, also this copied file gives me the same error, and doesn't open... but nobody has changed it!

Comment: Me too!  Can't figure it out.  Sometimes they will open sometimes not.   Most of the time, if I rebuild everything, then restart visual studio, and reload the solution, I will be able to open the Class Diagrams fine.    This is hardly a "Solution" though.    It seems to be more likely to happen after I do external source control operations where the code changes on disk rather than through visual studio, and studio doesn't catch-up correctly...?

Comment: Have you tried starting Visual Studio with logging enabled (`devenv /log`)? This will log issues to "%APPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Version\ActivityLog.xml".